# Python sns.catplot sum of group by

Tags: python

Tryin to do a sum of all minutes.

When doing just a DataFrame - receiving just a first value

```
sns.catplot(x="hour", hue="VehicleType", kind="count",
        palette="pastel", edgecolor=".6",
        data=df_test);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl8jl.png)

When doing with a group by (that is what I want to see) - getting the MAX value of 1

```
sns.catplot(x="hour", hue="VehicleType", kind="count",
        palette="pastel", edgecolor=".6",
        data=df_hour_group);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xKNh.png)

How I can show a group by sum with 2 categories, 24 hours?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

okay, figure that out

Don't need to use group by. Use pivot instead

```
df_plot= pd.pivot_table(df_test, columns='VehicleType', index=['hour'], aggfunc='sum', values='Minutes_Idling').plot(kind='bar')
```